Anchor position incorrect when using position-try-options and element is in the overflow
Take the following example:


const container = document.getElementById('container')

let html = ''

for (let i = 1; i < 149; i++) {
  html += `<div class="tooltip">
              <button class="trigger"
                popovertarget="tooltip-${i}"
                style="anchor-name: --tooltip-${i}">${i}</button>

              <div popover id="tooltip-${i}" class="content" style="position-anchor: --tooltip-${i}">
               Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
               A adipisci aliquam asperiores at aut beatae corporis, 
               cupiditate ea eaque error hic maxime.
              </div>
            </div>`
}

container.innerHTML = html
#container {
  background: #484848;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 50px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 80px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.trigger {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: flex;
  color: #000;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:has(+: popover-open) {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
  }
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 220px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 12px;
  inset-area: right span-bottom;
  position-try-options: flip-block, flip-inline, flip-block flip-inline;
}
<div id="container"></div>



Note: This issue is dependant on screen size.
In the preview, if you click on '1' then the tooltip shows to the right and flows down.

If you click on the tooltip to the far right and bottom of the page without scrolling (e.g 14 if using the default preview size) the tooltip goes to the left and flows up.

If you then scroll the page down and click on 38 for example, the tooltip flows upwards even though there is room below. All tooltips below the fold (requires scrolling to see) flow upwards regardless of where it is positioned on the page.

I would expect this tooltip to flow downwards. Is this a bug, intended behaviour, or have I misunderstood how position-try-options works?

(Note that position-try-options is experimental and not well supported : CanIUse)

I'm viewing this in Chrome where it states it is fully supported

I do too but it's interesting to specify to others that it is needed to use a specific browser to see the problem.

@TemaniAfif If you decrease the height of your screen so tooltips hide in the overflow, then scroll down and click on a tooltip, the content flows down for you? Just checking I got that requirement clear in the description.

the tooltip never overflow in my case, it's always visible

I've tested in the latest version of chrome and edge and am still getting the issue. So I'm probably just not explaining the problem clearly.

You want to set inset: auto; margin: 0; on the .content element.
The user agent adds inset: 0px; margin: auto; to elements with the popover attribute, which centers popovers by default.
